# TypeError: MyUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_superuser - Django REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework for my REST API.

I am creating a custom user model.
Here is my code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.db import models
import time

# Create your models here.
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, **kwargs):
        if(not email):
           raise ValueError("No Email Provided!")

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email, **kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, first_name, last_name, email, password, **kwargs ):
        kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)


        if(kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True):
           raise ValueError("Super User must be a staff in order to be in!")

        if(kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True):
           raise ValueError("User must be a SuperUser!")

        if(kwargs.get('is_active') is not True):
           raise ValueError("Super User must be active!")

        return self.create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, **kwargs)



class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 200, blank= False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 200, blank= False)
    email = models.EmailField(unique= True, blank= False)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 200, blank= False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True, null= False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default= False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default= True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number', 'company_name']

    objects = MyUserManager()
```

Here is the Error that I am getting:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)

File "C:\Users\Desktop\Auth-App\AuthProject\AuthApplication\models.py", line 33, in create_superuser
return self.create_user(first_name, last_name, email, password, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Desktop\Auth-App\AuthProject\AuthApplication\models.py", line 13, in create_user
user = self.model(email, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 500, in __init__
raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
```

TypeError: MyUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_superuser'

**What is a possible solution to the above problem ?**

Comment: Your `MyUser` has no `is_superuser` field. Typically users have an `is_superuser = models.BooleanField()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit MyUser from AbstractUser instead from AbstractBaseUser. In fact, `is_superuser` [is set in PermissionMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L237-L244), used by AbstractUser. In AbstractBaseUser, this necessary var does not exists.

So the solution is simply :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
```

Comment: poor answer. Based on OP's code, they want to make the email the unique identifier. Using `AbstractUser` will use `username` as the unique identifier for your `User`s, instead of email, which goes against their intended design. `AbstractBaseUser` can be still be used but the `MyUser` class needs to also extend `PermissionsMixin`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbstractBaseUser` but will also need to extend `PermissionsMixin`, as `is_superuser` is defined in `PermissionsMixin`.

`PermissionsMixin` is where the Group & Permission models are set.

Your `MyUser` class should look something like this:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
```

Here's a helpful tutorial/guide: [link](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/).